Python Logging : name 'log' is not defined
I am using python logging to write debug information to a file and print it to my screen :
logger=logging.getLogger() 
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

file_handler = logging.FileHandler("std.log", mode='w')
file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(file_handler)

logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout))

class MeuManipulador(logging.Handler):
    def emit(self, record):
        if record.levelno == logging.ERROR:
            log_entry = self.format(record)
            if "No such comm target registered" in str(record.msg):
                return
            log(mensagem = log_entry)    
logger.addHandler(MeuManipulador())

Everuthing runs fine, but on the end of my long code there is a code where logger.info or logger.warning runs ok.
logger.info('Dropando a tabela anterior')
with enginedb2 as conn:
    try:
        sql = ''' drop table DB2I023A.CNFC_CNV_HST_CTBL'''
        conn.execute(text(sql))
        conn.commit()
        logger.info(f'comando SQL {sql} executado com sucesso')
        time.sleep(1)
    except ResourceClosedError as error:
        logger.warning(f'comando SQL {sql} não foi executado com sucesso, resultando no erro : {error}')
        pass

But if I use logger.error, I get this!
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ResourceClosedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
File <timed exec>:5

File /projeto/libs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1418, in Connection.execute(self, statement, parameters, execution_options)
   1417 else:
-> 1418     return meth(
   1419         self,
   1420         distilled_parameters,
   1421         execution_options or NO_OPTIONS,
   1422     )

File /projeto/libs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py:515, in ClauseElement._execute_on_connection(self, connection, distilled_params, execution_options)
    514         assert isinstance(self, Executable)
--> 515     return connection._execute_clauseelement(
    516         self, distilled_params, execution_options
    517     )
    518 else:

File /projeto/libs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1640, in Connection._execute_clauseelement(self, elem, distilled_parameters, execution_options)
   1632 compiled_sql, extracted_params, cache_hit = elem._compile_w_cache(
   1633     dialect=dialect,
   1634     compiled_cache=compiled_cache,
   (...)
   1638     linting=self.dialect.compiler_linting | compiler.WARN_LINTING,
   1639 )
-> 1640 ret = self._execute_context(
   1641     dialect,
   1642     dialect.execution_ctx_cls._init_compiled,
   1643     compiled_sql,
   1644     distilled_parameters,
   1645     execution_options,
   1646     compiled_sql,
   1647     distilled_parameters,
   1648     elem,
   1649     extracted_params,
   1650     cache_hit=cache_hit,
   1651 )
   1652 if has_events:

File /projeto/libs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:1813, in Connection._execute_context(self, dialect, constructor, statement, parameters, execution_options, *args, **kw)
   1812 if conn is None:
-> 1813     conn = self._revalidate_connection()
   1815 context = constructor(
   1816     dialect, self, conn, execution_options, *args, **kw
   1817 )

File /projeto/libs/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py:680, in Connection._revalidate_connection(self)
    679     return self._dbapi_connection
--> 680 raise exc.ResourceClosedError("This Connection is closed")

ResourceClosedError: This Connection is closed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File <timed exec>:10

File /usr/local/lib/python3.11/logging/__init__.py:1518, in Logger.error(self, msg, *args, **kwargs)
   1509 """
   1510 Log 'msg % args' with severity 'ERROR'.
   1511 
   (...)
   1515 logger.error("Houston, we have a %s", "major problem", exc_info=1)
   1516 """
   1517 if self.isEnabledFor(ERROR):
-> 1518     self._log(ERROR, msg, args, **kwargs)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.11/logging/__init__.py:1634, in Logger._log(self, level, msg, args, exc_info, extra, stack_info, stacklevel)
   1631         exc_info = sys.exc_info()
   1632 record = self.makeRecord(self.name, level, fn, lno, msg, args,
   1633                          exc_info, func, extra, sinfo)
-> 1634 self.handle(record)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.11/logging/__init__.py:1644, in Logger.handle(self, record)
   1637 """
   1638 Call the handlers for the specified record.
   1639 
   1640 This method is used for unpickled records received from a socket, as
   1641 well as those created locally. Logger-level filtering is applied.
   1642 """
   1643 if (not self.disabled) and self.filter(record):
-> 1644     self.callHandlers(record)

File /usr/local/lib/python3.11/logging/__init__.py:1706, in Logger.callHandlers(self, record)
   1704     found = found + 1
   1705     if record.levelno >= hdlr.level:
-> 1706         hdlr.handle(record)
   1707 if not c.propagate:
   1708     c = None    #break out

File /usr/local/lib/python3.11/logging/__init__.py:978, in Handler.handle(self, record)
    976 self.acquire()
    977 try:
--> 978     self.emit(record)
    979 finally:
    980     self.release()

File <timed exec>:17, in emit(self, record)

NameError: name 'log' is not defined

Any tips? Is there any special requirements for logging.error!?

log is not defined to begin with, or where do you think it should be defined? It's just not used except for log level "error".

That is my doubt. I did not get where "log" where required. As some guys helped, it related to my custom handler. I have to look deeper on it to get where it does "use" the log (despite of not being directly used)

The issue arises because the emit method in your custom logging handler (MeuManipulador) refers to a log function that is not defined in your code:
log(mensagem = log_entry)

To resolve the NameError, you need to ensure that log is defined or replace it with the desired behavior. If you intend to log the error message differently or take specific action, define log appropriately or use a logger method.
If you simply want to log the error using another logger method:
class MeuManipulador(logging.Handler):
    def emit(self, record):
        if record.levelno == logging.ERROR:
            log_entry = self.format(record)
            if "No such comm target registered" in str(record.msg):
                return
            logger.error(log_entry)  # Log the error message


Thanks, but I still don´t get. The custom handler comes from a logging.Handler hierarchy. Where does it use a "log" function?

It doesn’t exist. You mistakenly called it without defining it.

I think, you should define log() function before the custom handler class.
You can define it like this,
def log(mensagem):
    print(mensagem)

